# Python 2D lists appending data to a location

Tags: python

Wondering if someone can help me on this.  I know I can append data to a 1D list by using .append.  What I am having trouble figuring out is how to append data to a 2D list and have Python place the data in the right list in the right spot.

I need to create a program that runs x times (with each name having 2 pairs of values), and after each time append the user input to a list. So at the end, I need something like this:

```
[[Name] [1,2] [3,4]]

[[Name] [4,5] [6,7]]
```

etc….

How do I tell Python which List and position to place the Names and values in ?
This is what I have so far for code.

```
def main():
    how_many = int(raw_input("How many to enter? "))
    counter = 0
    list = [ [], [] ]

    while counter < how_many:
        name = raw_input("Enter the Name ")
        first_val = int(raw_input("Enter first_val "))
        first_val2 = int(raw_input("Enter first_val2  "))
        sec_val = int(raw_input("Enter sec_val "))
        sec_val2 = int(raw_input("Enter sec_val2 "))
        counter = counter + 1
main()
```

**OK -** so I modified the code and added in a line to append the data, after the line with the counter + 1.

```
list.append([[name],[first_val,first_val2], [sec_val,sec_val2]])
```

What I would now like to do is print the list out (via rows and columns), but am getting a IndexError.  This occurs when I try to enter/print out more than 4 values. The error appears to be in the last line.  Is there a way I can modify the code to stop this and print out as many values as have been requested by the user ?

```
for r in range(how_many):
    for c in range (how_many):
        print list [r][c]
```

And yes, I will look into using tuples as well at some point.

Answer (score 2):

```
def main():
    how_many = int(raw_input("How many to enter? "))
    counter = 0
    list = []

    while counter < how_many:
        name = raw_input("Enter the Name ")
        first_val = int(raw_input("Enter first_val "))
        first_val2 = int(raw_input("Enter first_val2  "))
        sec_val = int(raw_input("Enter sec_val "))
        sec_val2 = int(raw_input("Enter sec_val2 "))
        list.append([[name], [first_val, first_val2], [sec_val, sec_val2]])
        counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we are reading the values from stdin (as in the question body)

you can use lists:

```
list = []
....
list.append([[name], [first_val, first_val2], [sec_val, sec_val2]])
```

but a tuple seems to be a better fit here:

```
t = (name, (first_val, first_val2), (sec_val, sec_val2))
list.append(t)
```

Since the values are not likely to change, a tuple feels like the better choice.

Think about how a field would be accessed in each case:

```
list:
name = list[i][0][0]
tuple:
name = list[i][0]
```

Again...it just seem more natural...